# I'm getting a SegFault on the 19th time my addNode function runs and I can't figure out why

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I run this code and no matter what inputs I use I get a segfault on the 19th time through the addNode function every time.  I'm new to c and am nearing my wits end here.  Anyone have any ideas?  I'm only looking for a general reason why it might happen, not anything specific to my case.  This is after all a school assignment and I don't want to violate any academic integrity rules.

```
int addNode(size_t t, Node** ht){
    Node* n = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    int hashVal = hash(t);
    n->value = t;
    if (ht[hashVal] == NULL){
        ht[hashVal] = n;
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        Node* nptr = ht[hashVal];
        while (nptr != NULL){
            if (nptr->value == t){
                return 0;
            }
            nptr = nptr->next;
        }
        nptr->next = n;
    }
    ht[hashVal] = n;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the calling code as well

Comment: how is `ht` defined?

Comment: `nptr->next = n;` : `(NULL)->next = n`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Add that as an answer.

Comment: BLUEPIXY was right.  how do I add it as an answer?

Comment: @ScottCorbett you can't; either hope BLUEPIXY comes back, or answer your own question.

Comment: After the `n=malloc()` (please don't cast it) you set `n->value = t;` but you should also set `n->next = NULL;` since `malloc()` does not initialise memory. At the first `if (ht[hashVal] == NULL)` you plug in the new pointer malloced with `ht[hashVal] = n;` but it has a dangling `next` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your function with the following changes:

1. Set `n->next`, which was missing before.
2. Rewrite if-else to utilize common code outside of block.
3. Fix memory leak if node already exists in hash.
4. Removed improper `nptr->next = n;` line.  If you wanted to add to the tail, you can do something like this but you are off by one.

```c
int addNode(size_t t, Node** ht)
{
    Node* n = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    int hashVal = hash(t);
    n->value = t;
    if (ht[hashVal] != NULL) {  // <-- Rewrote if, removed else
        Node* nptr = ht[hashVal];
        while (nptr != NULL){
            if (nptr->value == t) {
                free(n);  // <-- Memory leak if you don't do this
                return 0;
            }
            nptr = nptr->next;
        }
    }
    n->next = ht[hashVal]; // <-- This was missing
    ht[hashVal] = n;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few problems:

1) You leak memory if you find an already matching entry.
2) You don't properly set `n`'s child in the base case (i.e. - ht[hashVal] == NULL).
3) You loop too far looking for the end of the list and then try to deref a NULL pointer.
4) You set the head of the list to be the new node but don't link it to the rest of the list (similar to 2) while you also try to link the new node onto the end of the existing list.  Pick one or the other: either insert it at the head of the list or append it to the end of the list.

Here's a cleaner version of what I think you are after:

```
int addNode(size_t t, Node** ht)
{
    int   hashVal = hash(t);
    Node *n       = ht[hashVal];

    // check if t is already in ht

    while (NULL != n)
    {
      if (n->value == t)
        return 0;

      n = n->next;
    }

    // insert t at the head of the hash bucket list

    if (NULL == (n = malloc(sizeof(Node))))
      return -1;

    n->value = t;
    n->next  = ht[hashVal];
    ht[hashVal] = n;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a pointer-to-pointer, you should use that:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
        struct node *next;
        size_t value;
        } Node;

#define ZSIZE 5 

Node *hashtab[ZSIZE] = {NULL,};
size_t hash(size_t val)
{
return val % ZSIZE;
}

int addNode(size_t t, Node **ht)
{
    Node *new;
    size_t hashVal ;

    hashVal = hash(t);
    for (ht += hashVal; *ht; ht = &(*ht)->next ) {
        if ((*ht)->value == t) return 0;
        }

    new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    new->value = t;
    new->next = NULL;
    *ht = new;
    return 1;
}
```

---

And something to test it with:

---

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
size_t val;
Node *p;

/* assume argv[1] ... argv[n] contains numbers */    
for (argv++; *argv; argv++) {
    sscanf(*argv, "%zu", &val);
    addNode(val, hashtab);
    }

/* print the complete contents of the hashtable */
for (val=0; val < ZSIZE; val++) {
    for (p=hashtab[val]; p; p = p->next) {
            printf("%zu\n", p->value );
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```